# Remove shippping estimation for specific state

Tags: magento-1.9

I just want to show "contact us" message when customer selects alaska state. just want disable all shipping estimations for this state.

Comment: have you thought about using jQuery as a simple hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding the method *checkAvailableShipCountries* in Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract so that a region check is also performed. If the region matches your disabled state. i.e. Alaska then a contact us message is returned.

Here is the code example in **app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php** added to the *checkAvailableShipCountries* method around line 237.

```
    if ($request->getDestCountryId() === 'US') {
        $region=Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load($request->getDestRegionId());
        if ($region->getName() === 'Alaska')
        {
               $error = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
               $error->setCarrier($this->_code);
               $error->setCarrierTitle('Contact Us');
               $error->setErrorMessage(Mage::helper('shipping')->__('Contact Us'));
               return $error;
        }
    }
```

You should modify this core module code either in a custom module, or by copying the file to app/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php and making the changes there.

A neater solution would be to define the restricted Country/Regions via the admin interface.

Tested with shipping estimate, and order. The customer will not be able to place an order if they try and ship to the restricted region. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegion() by calling this function in my phtml file frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml i achieved